# Word JS Api: Access Denied on Body.getOoxml

Tags: office-js, office-addins

My problem is very similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898458/word-js-api-access-denied-contentcontrol-select-body-gethtml). However, the answer of that question is for  `select()`, and I need a solution for `body.getOoxml()`.

I have this simple code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var xml = context.document.body.getOoxml();
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        // do something
    });
}).catch(errorHandlerDS);

...

function errorHandlerDS(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

My Word version is `16.0.4266.1001` and I am getting this error:

```
{
    "name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "AccessDenied",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "debugInfo": {
        "errorLocation": "Body.getOoxml"
    },
    "stack": "AccessDenied: AccessDenied\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:150094)\n at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163912)\n at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163999)\n at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:163819)\n at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.00.js:19:162405)" 
}
```

In newer versions of Word this code is running well and it isn't throwing any exception. However, my client don't want to update his Office versions. Is there a way to make the code work on that version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Word is quite finicky with the correct load order in the older versions.

```
const body = context.document.body;
await context.sync();
const xml = body.getOoxml();
await context.sync();
// do something
```

It may or may not work though, knowing word...

Comment: I tried to load body first and then body.getOoxml, but it is still giving me an AccessDenied error.

Comment: @EstevaoLuis Sorry, i can't reproduce it, don't have an older version to test it in. :(